# How to configure deep linking with http or https domain with expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want when I click on a link in my domain like http://example.com that my application is open. I understood that deep linking is only with the custom scheme. Is it feasible with the scheme http or https. If so, how can I do this with Expo ???